# How to fix undefined behaviour with considerably small changes in code

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

In the core of our project we have following code:

```
template<typename T>
T& get_factory_instance(bool reset = false)
{
   static boost::scoped_ptr<T> factory_instance;
   if (reset)
   {
      factory_instance.reset();
      return *(T*)0;
   }
   if (!factory_instance)
   {
      factory_instance.reset(new T());
   }
   return *factory_instance;
}
```

If `reset` is `true`, that it's UB according to standard.

This function with argument `true` is called only when return value is ignored, so, memory is not accessed. It's mandatory, function cannot be called from services, only from libraries, when we add call of this function to singleton list of functions with signature `void()`. We need such strange hack for clearing prepared statement connected to the database, if connection lost.

So, basically question is: can it fire, if we don't access this memory? And if yes, how can we possibly fix it without rewriting all code dependent on this function, if there is any possibility?

When `T` constructor is called it constructs prepared statement and open/use connection to the database, so, creating dummy object is not pretty idea.

We have near 80 calls of this function with argument `true` in out libraries. It was introduced in 2015. Code that uses this function without argument in most cases looks like:

```
fields_t& fields = get_factory_instance<fields_t>();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could return a reference to a dummy `static` instance. You would be returning non-const references to a sentinel value, which is not great, but at least it wouldn't be UB.

Comment: is there any call that passes `false` explicitly? or is it either `()` or `(true)` ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, problem is, that object is using database, in constructor it receives, or create session. Creating session, without using it is not good idea.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `reset` flag? Should not not cause the factory instance to be recreated? What problem is that flag supposed to solve to begin with?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, no, it's purpose is only to reset prepared statement connected to the database (on database error, for example connection lost), so, when another request comes new db session will be created and new prepared statement will be created.

Comment: @ForEveR If your function has a reference return type, you must return a reference to an object. The only way around that is to not return (terminate or throw (but those aren't solutions here)). If `fields_t` is not default constructible, that is probably a design error. If it is moveable, then there is no reason not to provide a default constructor. If it is not moveable, consider refactoring it to use the Pimpl pattern.

Comment: What's this: "return *(T*)0;" ? OMG

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson> that is the point of the question, finding a replacement for this.

Comment: Another design error seems to be that the factory appears to be stateful, if it needs to be recreated for each instance it creates. It isn't really a factory, and it shouldn't be global.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yeah. There are few overloads of this function, all do the same, but have different template arguments/function arguments. We are trying to find how we can possibly decrement count of changes in code. From 2015 many code was written...

Comment: To me this looks more like a design flaw, or possible a flaw in implementing the design. I would explicitly split the functionality into two functions: One for reset (if it's really needed by the requirements), and one to get the factory object.

Comment: @ForEveR It looks to me like `get_factory_instance` is a fundamentally broken design and your team should bite the bullet and just fix it properly (refactor it). 80 call sites is significant, but it isn't overwhelming.

Comment: Resetting singletons is anti-pattern! Try to check out why "reset" must sometimes be true. If possible remove the parameter and simplefy the function to just return the singleton.

Comment: As a frame challenge: is changing call sites totally unimaginable? A custom clang-tidy rule might be able to do the job quite reliably. That does require you have access to all call sites though.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson> that is totally off-topic, but I find it annoying the OMG earlier and the LOL here. We all have to deal with legacy code written by someone who left the company years ago some day. It's annoying already without having someone laugh on a serious question. Please :)

Comment: You could write a class that is implicitly convertible to `T&` to wrap the reference, and add the concept of nullability. Then, the function would not have UB. But the way the function is being used, it is not possible to avoid the UB caused by `fields_t& fields = ` no matter the return type. In my opinion, this is impossible to achieve in C++ without updating the call sites or returning a reference to a dummy object.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson, mate, this code was written in 2015 year, It was written by programmer with 10+ years experience. Yes, that's UB, but it should have been fixed quickly, cause any DB connection lost leads to prepared statements works with closed connection.

Comment: To minimize code changes, I'd lean towards separate get/reset functions, with possibly a 3rd private one to hold the static local (or a static class member).

Comment: 10+ years experience? With my 3+ in C++ I interpret "return *(T*)0;" this like, cast zero to a pointer of T, then dereference a pointer of nothing (NULL as T) -> BOOM.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson, so, what's the problem if you don't use this memory more? Man, it's clearly offtopic. I know, that it's bad code, which leads to UB, but that was done. It's not my code through, so, your words are misdirected.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, about refactoring - yeah, thanks. We will do this of course, if there is no other choice. I have just asked a question to probably find some way, which I don't know.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, is it really matter? Well, we have few overloads, but reset is either true, or function is called without reset arg.

Comment: if thats the case, you can write two overloads `void get_factory_instance(bool)` and `T& get_factory_instance()` the actual isntance is stored in some `get_factory_isntance_impl`

Comment: I think it has already been mentioned, but the only way to avoid the ub is to not return the reference when you have no object you could refer to, so calling a `void` function is the only option I see

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, well, it's clearly great idea, if compiler can distinguish calls. I will try through.

Comment: @ForEveR That should work well, as long as any use of `get_factory_instance(true)` doesn't try to store the return value, and as long as nobody decided to do `get_factory_instance(false)`.

Comment: AFAICT you can return a reference to any object (possibly suitably aligned), cast to `T&`. As long the result is not used, you are OK.

Comment: Hello everyone - this comment thread is getting kind of long. I'm not saying that it's currently problematic, but we might want to think about a chat room if it's going to get appreciably longer (comment threads here are hard to wade through, difficult to reply to, and can vanish) - I don't want to kill the conversation, I just want to make sure it takes place in the right place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that this is legacy code and you want to have no changes on the calls if possible. Further I assume all calls to the function are either

```
fields_t& fields = get_factory_instance<fields_t>();
```

or

```
get_factory_instance<fields_t>(true);
```

In other words, you never call it via

```
fields_t& fields = get_factory_instance<fields_t>(false);
```

Though as you will see, this actually wouldn't be a big issue, because with the following solution it would result in a compiler error and can be fixed easily.

You can refactor to:

```
template<typename T>
boost::scoped_ptr<T>& get_impl(){
    static boost::scoped_ptr<T> instance;
    return instance;
}
// or store the instance elsewhere
// and then...

template <typename T>
void get_factory_instance(bool) {
    get_impl<T>().reset();
}

template<typename T>
T& get_factory_instance() {
   auto& factory_instance = get_impl<T>();
   if (!factory_instance)
   {
      factory_instance.reset(new T());
   }
   return *factory_instance;
}
```

Alternatively, do use some dummy default static `T` to which you can return a reference, though that would be rather wasteful.

In general, you cannot safely return a `T&` when you have no `T` to refer to, so making the "reset" calls call a `void` function is the only option i see.

---

Well ok, instead of adding a `void` overload you could return a proxy object that only converts to `T&` when requested by the caller. Take this with a grain of salt, it is definitely more error prone than the above. I am not really recommending it, it is merely to show another possibility:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct maybe_ref_from_ptr { // first attempt of naming was optional_... but thats too misleading
    T* ptr;
    operator T& () { return *ptr; }
};

template <typename T>
maybe_ref_from_ptr<T> foo(bool reset = false) {
    static T* p = nullptr;
    if (reset ) {
        if(p) delete p;
        p = nullptr;
    } else {
        if (p == nullptr) p = new T(42);
    }
    return {p};
}

int main(){
    int& i = foo<int>();
    std::cout << i;
    foo<int>(true);
    int& j = foo<int>();
    std::cout << j;
}
```

For the real case the proxy would have to be adjusted to not simple store a raw pointer to a `T` but appropriate smart pointer. The obvious downside is that now the responsibility to avoid the UB is on the caller. Though you could `throw` in `operator T&` when the pointer isnt valid... I admit I didn't think this through completely, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: That's clearly a solution. I checked all my codebase:
grep -r get_factory_instance --include=*.cpp * | grep false and nothing showed. Thank you very much. I will accept this answer, after testing new code.

Comment: Is not that true, that if we don't use default argument and we ensure that there are no calls with false, so we just return either void, either T&, we will not get UB anywhere?

Comment: @ForEveR are you refering to the `bool reset = true` in my code? That doesn't really matter, I could remove it. Once you made sure the function is only called without parameter or `true` the function could even be just `void get_factory_instance(bool) { get_impl<T>().reset(); }`, though I'd perhaps leave the `assert(reset == true)` to prevent someone accidentally calling `get_factory_instance(false)`

Comment: Isn't assert fires on execution, not on compilation?

Comment: @ForEveR runtime unfortunately. On a second thought I guess its not needed. I am just a little paranoic. I was considering for example someone taking a function pointer to the wrong function without noticing but already the different return type will prevent that. I removed it from the answer...